# bash: test: no: integer expression expected

Tags: bash, shell-script, test

I believe this line

```
if test "$suman_inspect" -eq "yes"; then
```

is causing this error (verbatim):

```
bash: test: no: integer expression expected
```

I formulated the above `test` expression because I saw this example online:

```
 if test "$#" -eq "0"; then
```

where this test checks to see if the length of the arguments array is 0.

So is there something wrong with both these checks? I am not sure I understand how the first could be valid but the second one invalid.

Comment: Both test expressions in the question are invalid - to compare strings you need to use the `==` operator, not the `-eq` operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `-eq` is for integer comparisons. For string comparisons, use `==` (or [`=`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions)). Thus, you should use the following:

```
if test "$suman_inspect" == "yes"; then
    # do something
fi
```

The same distinction applies for inequality operators (`-gt`, `-lt`, `-ge`, `-le`, and `-ne` being used for numerical comparisons, and `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`, and `!=` being used for string comparisons).

Note that you can also use `[ expression ]` in place of `test expression`; the two are [synonymous](https://ss64.com/bash/test.html).

Comment: yeah it's a shame the `-eq` operator cannot compare two strings, as long as both arguments are already strings, oh well.

Comment: @Alexander Mills: I have long thought that `eq`, being a string, should be used for string comparisons, while `=`, being a mathematical symbol, should be used for numerical comparisons, but alas it's not the case.

Comment: no language is perfect lol

Comment: @AlexanderMills String and integer comparisons are different, so it's important to have different symbols for them. For instance, `[ 05 -eq 5 ]` is true, but `[ 05 = 5 ]` is not -- they're different strings that represent the same integer. Also, `[ 5 -lt 11 ]` is true, but `[ 5 '<' 11 ]` is not, because 5 is less than 11 numerically, but comes after it "alphabetically" (i.e. in sorting order). BTW, `=` is preferred over `==` with `test` and `[ ]`, for compatibility reasons.